# How do I search for occurrence of a string and text above and beneath it in a very large file

Tags: java, search, groovy, large-files

I want to search for a string in a large gz file and also want to check some text i.e. 10 lines above and below it. ... i cannot use any editor search facility because it takes a very long time to load in memory and sometimes the editors even crash on opening the file. What would be the best way to search through this very large file for some search string like
4296708614 for eg .. Any unix utility that would be handy ? or if i could write a language code for it in Java or groovy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain old grep will do. Pass in `-C N` to display N lines of context around each match.

Comment: I entered this at the command line according to what you said but this ends up printing the whole file .. how do i print 5 lines around the matched search string "4296708614"  ------------>                               grep -C 5 4296708614 IPCM_20111216172222_00363.xml.gz.transit

Comment: @Phoenix: I just tried that and it works fine. Are you sure your file isn't one big line? Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: oh yeah! it does look like one big line when i try to open it in an editor .. Is there anyway to get around it ?

Comment: @Phoenix: You talked about "lines" in your original post, how did you see these lines?

Comment: It just floods the console with the file text but I realized that is the case because the file is just one big line when I open it a xml editor. So, the context with lines command for grep will not work here. Is there anyway where I can output may be few words or something around the search string, or delimit the lines in the file with a newline char ? Wondering which one is the simplest to do ?